# How to show that the following function is continuous at 0?

Tags: real-analysis

Define a function $f$ as

$$ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{p}{q^2},  & \text{if $x \in \Bbb Q,$ $p,q\in \Bbb Z $ $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime} \\
x^2, & \text{if $x \notin \Bbb Q$}
\end{cases}$$

Is $f$ continues at $x=0$ ?

I understand that I have to prove or disprove that the limit exists at $0$, i.e. prove or disprove that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ so that if $0<|x−0|<δ$ then $|f(x)−f(0)|<ϵ$. I am confused as to how I can actually go about this proof.

Comment: Hint: In a small nbhd of 0 $|f(x)| \le |x|$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $f(0)=0$, so we need to prove that for all $\epsilon$, there exists a $\delta$ such that $|x|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)|<\epsilon$. Since for $x<1$, $f(x)<x$, we see that setting $\delta=\min\{1,\epsilon\}$ gives us the desired result, as when $|x|<\epsilon$, we immediately get $|f(x)|<|x|<\epsilon$ and when $\epsilon>1$, $|x|<1\Rightarrow |f(x)|<1<\epsilon$

Answer (score -1):

Let $\epsilon \in (0,1), \delta = \epsilon < \sqrt\epsilon$. $\forall x $ such that $0\le|x|\le\delta$,

- If $x \in \Bbb Q$, $|f(x)-f(0)| = |\frac{p}{q^2}-0|\le |\frac{p}{q}| \le |x| \le \delta=\epsilon$
- If $x \notin \Bbb Q$, $|f(x)-f(0)| = |x^2 - 0| \le \delta^2 \le \epsilon$.

Hence $f$ is continuous at $x = 0$.